# How to prevent duplicates within foreach PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, foreach

I'm trying to move customer order notes field to another field group, but because of other plugin overrides, I need to override WooCommerce template files too, so I need to move this code:

```
foreach ( $checkout->get_checkout_fields( 'order' ) as $key => $field ) :
    woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) ); 
endforeach;
```

from: "*mytheme/woocommerce/checkout/form-shipping.php*"
to: "*mytheme/woocommerce/checkout/review-order.php*".

Now I'm getting duplicated fields, how to prevent duplicates within foreach loop?

Comment: may be [array_unique()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_unique.asp) will help you

Comment: @Paritosh Mahale maybe, but where?

Comment: In your foreach loop: `foreach ( array_unique($checkout->get_checkout_fields('order')) as $key => $field )`

Comment: checkout my answer

Comment: @SteveK not working with `array_unique`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can maintain an `array` to keep track of fields you've already seen so that they don't get added again.

```php
$fields_seen = [];
foreach ( $checkout->get_checkout_fields( 'order' ) as $key => $field ) :
    if(!in_array($field, $fields_seen)) {
        woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) ); 
        $fields_seen[] = $field;
    }
endforeach;
```

Reference page for in_array: [PHP in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: Thanks, but still getting 2 same fields.

Comment: Are the values duplicates of `$field` or `$checkout->get_value( $key )`? If the latter, then you need to check for the existence of that in the `in_array` call instead.

Comment: Values of  `$field` are duplicates.

Comment: This code would prevent duplicates of `$field` as it's being added to an array and then checked for the following value. You can confirm with `print_r($fields_seen)` to review what fields made it to your `woocommerce_form_field()` call. Maybe it's something within the woocommerce call itself, meaning we're not checking the right variables or it's at the wrong step.

Comment: What type is `$field`?

Comment: `$field` is an array.

Comment: `print_r($fields_seen)` gives
`Array ( [0] => Array ( [type] => textarea [name] => order_comments [label] => Order Notes [default] => [placeholder] => Notes about your order, e.g. special notes for delivery. [class] => Array ( [0] => notes [1] => thwcfd-field-wrapper [2] => thwcfd-field-textarea ) [validate] => [disp_style] => [required] => 0 [enabled] => 1 [show_in_email] => 0 [show_in_order] => 0 [options] => [autocomplete] => [priority] => 10 [custom] => 0 ) ) `

Comment: This means there's only one entry in `$checkout->get_checkout_fields( 'order' )`, which happens to be an array filled with a lot of information (containing duplicate values for different keys). Are you trying to remove the duplicates from the nested array instead?

Comment: Well, it appears so

Comment: Please revert to your previous code, it was working OK, I just figured that the field is being duplicated by some JavaScript.

Comment: Is this what you wanted it reverted to?

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [array_unique()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_unique.asp) 
your code will look like this:

```
foreach ( array_unique($checkout->get_checkout_fields( 'order' )) as $key => $field ) :
    woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) ); 
endforeach;
```

Comment: Since `$field` is of type array, `array_unique()` may not work as intended.